# Rails 6 action text required true not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1, trix

I have the following form using action text and trix in Rails 6.1:

```
<%= form_for :job, url: job_create_path, method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :description, class: "text-muted" do %>
    Job Description <span class="lighter"> * required</span>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.rich_text_area :description, required: true, :placeholder=>"Job Description...", :class=>"form-control", :id=>"description" %>
<% end %>
```

I have a backend validation that works well. However, I would like to add a frontend validation as well. 'Required true' seems not to work on 'rich_text_area'. Does anybody know how to add a frontend validation as well?

Comment: https://github.com/maclover7/trix/issues/24 you would have to add that validation manually using javascript probably

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm trying to set the hidden field as required using js, but still won't perform front end validation. I noticed this https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/328. I wonder does that mean that this is not possible?

Comment: Yes because the Trix editor is not a native HTML element, you can add JS to disable the submit button or on form submit to check if the Trix editor has value or not.

Comment: Awesome. Will try catching the submission. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/328#issuecomment-256788015

> Browsers only support the required attribute for native input elements, unfortunately.

As the Trix editor is not a native HTML element it doesn't support `required: true`. You might have to use some custom JS to validate it.